# How to use split in linq query?

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call the following query string but I am getting 'no data' message on the client-side - 'api/data?id=786,899&price_type=cvr'.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
{
    var data = db.database_ICs.AsQueryable();

    if (query.id!= null)
    {
        data = data.Where(c => query.id.Split(',').Contains(c.ID));
    }
    if (query.price_type != null)
    {
        data = data.Where(c => c.Cover == query.price_type);
    }

    if (!data.Any())
    {
        var message = string.Format("No data was found");
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}

public class Query
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string price_type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> startDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> endDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Many Thanks.

Comment: Is `c.ID` of type string?

Comment: Is this `LINQ to SQL`? `LINQ to SQL` has no translation for `string.Split` to SQL.

Comment: hi @okrumnow, yes that is correct.

Comment: @DaveZych, I apologise for the lack of knowledge, as I new into programming web api's.  I am trying to implement the code, so it can pass multiple id records at the same(api/data?id=786&id=788&price-type=cvr). I assumed split function would work best here, but id there is a better way to do this, please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = db.database_ICs.AsQueryable();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.id))
        {
             var ids = query.id.Split(',').ToList();
             data = data.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID));
        }
```

Assuming c.ID and ids elements are of the same type of course. 
Edit: one way of checking if you have the querystring or not

Comment: What problem is converting it to a list solving?

Comment: It should create an IN the sql query against a set of values instead of trying to do .Split in sql

Comment: @AD.Net, thank you so much for your help. When I search just the 'price-type' parameter by itself(api/data?price-type=cvr), it throws up an null exception error - ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":", on the following line of code(var ids...).

Comment: you should check if query.id is not null